# Ubable to access the inbox of an email account using EWS: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

We are trying to access the inbox of an email account using EWS (https://mailserver.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx). But we keep getting the following error:

The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

My Source code is here:

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);                            
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain,     sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    service.Url = new Uri("https://mailserver.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("UserName", "Password", null);
    ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
```

//Error on this line

Comment: Are you working in domain?

Comment: @Maqsood, please edit your question to have '//Error on this line' show up on the source line code ;-)